# Lightning Tabset and Tab is same as lightning__tab

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, tab, lightning-tabset

Asking if why the tabset and tab are not the same with the default tab component on the lightning app builder. When I tried to create an aura component, and viewed in Salesforce Mobile App, then the UI will not change to vertical tab.

Tried to tweak it in css but no luck. :(

I want to show like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect the current device type and change the variant of the tab component in Aura to Vertical.

**To detect the device type use $Browser global value provider:-**

[$Browser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_browser_value_provider.htm)
The $Browser global value provider returns information about the hardware and operating system of the browser accessing the application.

```
<aura:component>
    {!$Browser.isTablet}
    {!$Browser.isPhone}
    {!$Browser.isAndroid}
    {!$Browser.formFactor}
</aura:component>
```

To apply vertical variant:-

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:tabset variant="vertical">
        <lightning:tab label="Item One">
            Content in Tab One
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Item Two">
            Content in Tab Two
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Item Three">
            Content in Tab Three
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Item Four">
            Content in Tab Four
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Item Five">
            Content in Tab Five
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Item Six">
            Content in Tab Six
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
</aura:component>
```

[image]

Comment: I added the screenshot of my goal.

Comment: Tab similar to lightning app builder component

Comment: When I used the vertical variant, it didn't flex/stretch the UI in mobile app

Comment: Why don't you use accordion with multiple section open equals true in mobile?